# Python: can an object add or edit values of its "brother"?

Tags: python, oop

Here is my code

```
import json


class Father(object):
    data = {}

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.data['name'] = name

    def dump_data(self):
        print(json.dumps(self.data))

class Brother(Father):

    def __init__(self, name, number_of_cars):
        self.set_name(name)
        self.set_number_of_cars(number_of_cars)

    def set_number_of_cars(self, n):
        self.data['number_of_cars'] = n

class Sister(Father):

    def __init__(self, name, number_of_dolls):
        self.set_name(name)
        self.set_number_of_dolls(number_of_dolls)

    def set_number_of_dolls(self, n):
        self.data['number_of_dolls'] = n


child = Brother('Brother John', 5)
child.dump_data()
child = Sister('Sister Jane', 30)
child.dump_data()
```

What I expected is

```
{"name": "Brother John", "number_of_cars": 5}
{"name": "Sister Jane", "number_of_dolls": 30}
```

But, the result is

```
{"name": "Brother John", "number_of_cars": 5}
{"number_of_dolls": 30, "name": "Sister Jane", "number_of_cars": 5}
```

And the result is still the same if I change like this

```
child1 = Sister('Sister Jane', 30)
child1.dump_data()
```

I don't know why this issue happens. I thought because I use the `data` attribute of `Father` class and `data` is dictionary (a mutable type in python), but I have 2 different objects of 2 different classes (inherited from one `Father` class), so that idea does not make sense to me. Where *Jane* have `number_of_cars` element?
The issue occurs on both Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.4.3.

Please explain me why this happens! Thank you!

Comment: `data` is a class property, not an instance property. So all instances of the class share the same property.

Comment: You need an `__init__` method in `Father` that does `self.data = {}` so each instance gets it own.

Comment: Unless it's just the naming that's a bit misleading here - the use of inheritance here is odd... A `Brother`/`Sister` aren't really `Father`s... rather they *have a `Father`*...  You might want to read up on OOP and inheritance before proceeding much further down this path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are initilizing `data` as a class property, not a instance property.

You have to move `data = {}` to `Father.__init__()` as `self.data = {}`.

```
import json


class Father(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.data['name'] = name

    def dump_data(self):
        print(json.dumps(self.data))


class Brother(Father):
    def __init__(self, name, number_of_cars):
        super(Brother, self).__init__()
        self.set_name(name)
        self.set_number_of_cars(number_of_cars)

    def set_number_of_cars(self, n):
        self.data['number_of_cars'] = n


class Sister(Father):
    def __init__(self, name, number_of_dolls):
        super(Sister, self).__init__()
        self.set_name(name)
        self.set_number_of_dolls(number_of_dolls)

    def set_number_of_dolls(self, n):
        self.data['number_of_dolls'] = n


child = Brother('Brother John', 5)
child.dump_data()
child = Sister('Sister Jane', 30)
child.dump_data()
```

And you get the expected result:

```
{"number_of_cars": 5, "name": "Brother John"}
{"number_of_dolls": 30, "name": "Sister Jane"}
```